# sql update statement node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, db2

I am having a problem with my update statement in sql, I am not sure if this is possible, but I am trying this:

```
var updateStudent = "update table set CHILDNAME2 = '" + req.body.childName + "', REPORT2 = '" + report + "', YEAR2 = '" + req.body.year + "', STARTDAY2 = '" + req.body.startDay + "', STARTTIME2 = '" + req.body.startTime + "', ENDTIME2 = '" + req.body.endTime + "', ENDDAY2 = '" + req.body.endDay + "', MONTH2 = '" + req.body.month + "' WHERE USERNAME = '" + req.body.username + "')"
```

it is giving me the error:

```
 [Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token ")" was found following "ERNAME = 'undefined'".  Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  SQLSTATE=42601
] {
  error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
  sqlcode: -104,
  state: '42601'
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.
thx for ur help :)

Comment: I think there's no open bracket (`(`) or remove last bracket. Your query looks like `UPDATE TABLE SET C='c', R='r', Y='y', S='s', E='e', M='m', WHERE USERNAME='req.body.username');` (C, R, Y, S, E, M is start-alphabet which is field want to change)

Comment: Well, yes, you have a closing bracket that - in theory - doesn't need to be there.  You also have a SQL statement that is potentially prone to SQL injection.  I'd suggest looking at available methods to execute parameterised queries that will reduce your SQL Injection risk.  Here's a basic starter - https://www.veracode.com/blog/secure-development/how-prevent-sql-injection-nodejs

Comment: Using parameterized queries is safer, and it's also easier! If you remove all that messy string-concatenation out of your code you will probably spot syntax mistakes more easily. For example: `UPDATE TABLE SET C=?, R=?, Y=?, S=?, E=?, M=?, WHERE USERNAME=?)` This lets you see the mismatched parenthesis right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to use parameterized queries to make your query less confusing. Also it's safer to use actually.

```
var updateStudent = `UPDATE table
SET CHILDNAME2 = ?,
REPORT2 = ? YEAR2 = ?,
STARTDAY2 = ?,
REPORT2 = ?,
YEAR2 = ?,
STARTTIME2 = ?,
ENDTIME2 = ?,
MONTH2 = ?
WHERE USERNAME = ?`;

let variables = [
    req.body.childName,
    report,
    req.body.year
    ...
];

con.query(updateStudent, variables, (err, fields, response) => {
    ...
});

let variables = [
    req.body.childName,
    report,
    req.body.year
    ...
];

con.query(updateStudent, variables), (err, fields, response) => {
    ...
});
```